# Replace newline in ntext

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-server-2012, ntext

One of the columns uses ntext. I want to replace the newlines and carriage returns in to space but I can only do it one at a time. Is there a way I could use `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(13)` at the same time using the script below on SQL Server 2012?

```
REPLACE(CAST(Description as NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(10), ' ') AS Description
```

Comment: Why are you using `ntext`?  Use `nvarchar(max)`.  Microsoft documentation specifically warns against using it:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.110).aspx.

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE(CAST(DESCRIPTION AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) ,'  ' ,' ') AS DESCRIPTION`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I dont have the rights to change the type anymore because it was setup as ntext the first time.

Answer (score 7):

To replace CRLF instances, you could use:

```
REPLACE(CAST(Description as NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), ' ') AS Description
```

To individually replace all CRs and LFs, you could use:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(Description as NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' ') AS Description
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
REPLACE(CAST(Description as NVARCHAR(MAX)), '
', ' ') AS Description
```